# How to create ear in ATG for further usage with disposable classloader?

Tags: classloader, atg

As it is said in ATG Platform programming guide in Appendix A p. 429 I can create ear file without including my module in ATG regular classpath (As I understood without placing my module in DYNAMO_ROOT directory), by specifying atg.nucleus.class.path in my DYNAMO_HOME/localconfig/postEnvironment.sh. After creating and deploying ear file I can modify java class and see the changes in application without rebuilding ear file and without redeploy using ATG Control Center. But in stage of assembling by runAssembler I'm getting an error:
Error:  There is no installed ATG platform or application package containing an AppModule which matches myModule.
Does someone have an experience of using disposable classloader?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating ear of atg application then there are two ways:

**1.)Development Mode** - In development mode, the application draws its Nucleus configuration information from the Oracle ATG Web Commerce installation.
In this mod you can make configuration changes without having to rebuild the EAR file.
eq. runAssembler MyApp.ear –m MyApp DSS

**2.)Standalone Mode** - In standalone mode, the application stores its configuration in the EAR file itself

eq. runAssembler **–standalone** –server myServer MyApp.ear –m MyApp DSS

Comment: I'm using only Development Mode, because of I cannot use disposable classloader under Standalone Mode.